# Как вывести все столбцы у строки где значение равно 1

Tags: python, sqlite3

В [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3) есть таблица `users`, в ней есть множество строк, где значения равны либо 0, либо 1, мне нужно вывести в этой таблице строку с пользователем, где значения этих столбцов равно именно одному. Код на языке [python](/questions/tagged/python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import sqlite3

sql = sqlite3.connect('имя.db')
conn = sql.cursor()

column = 'Введите свою колонку...'
users = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE `{}`= 1'.format(column)).fetchall()
for arr in users:
    print(arr) # Выведет все данные строк по условию
```

Чтобы выводить только нужное, то вводим нужный запрос:
*В примере указаны столбцы name, surname,number*

```py
users = conn.execute('SELECT `name`, `surname`, `number` FROM users WHERE `{}`= 1'.format(column)).fetchall()
```

Comment: а как не выводить порядковый номер строки(id)?

Comment: @panickx, добавил отдельно в ответ